# unable to get values from string using its key

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

Unable to get the values from `result` string object using its key as `name` in Android code

I want to fetch values from MySQL table and show it on dropdown
for that I write following code

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);              
List<String> mynamelist = (List<String>) json_data.getJSONArray("name");
return (List<String>) mynamelist;
```

debug values shown below for `result` and `json_data`
[image]

I want to return names only (ashish, john)
so I did like `(List<String>) json_data.getJSONArray("name");`

How do I get all values from `result`
check the image.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON code? I have a suspicious there is a parsing error going on

Comment: If you copied that error over, you probably made a typo in your `getJSONArray` call. The error says `nme` instead of `name`.

Comment: `nme` is actually a value of key `name` sorry for temp data updating question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these

`JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);

List<String> mynamelist = new List<String>();
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("arrayName");`
   `for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    mynamelist.add(jsonChildNode.optString("name"));
   }
return mynamelist;`

Comment: i think in json_data there is only one element value . we need to loop through `result` ? what you think?

Comment: Yes in these situation json_data.getJSONArray("name"); get just the first JSONArray {"name":"nme"} for more information about JSONArray and JSONOBJECT structure visit This page [link](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared the `JSON` but if your `JSON` is valid, and look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "nme"
    },
    {
        "name": "done"
    },
    {
        "name": "dinkol"
    }
]
```

Then the right way to parse it is too put it in a `JSONArray` object.
Loop through the `JSONObject` and append the value to your list array:

```
JSONArray json_data = new JSONArray(result);      

List<String> mynamelist = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < json_data.length(); i++){
    mynamelist.add(json_data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: getting same error on this line `JSONArray json_data = new JSONArray(result);   `

Comment: i think in json_data there is only one element value . we need to loop through` result`? what you think?